# MySQL select data based on months and sum them together (preferably in ZEND)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I have a fairly complicated MySQL query that I need help implementing in Zend Framework. I have a database named 'power' that is structured as follows:

```
    id |     addr         |      timestamp      | power1  | power2 |  serial           
    21 | FAS235DQ92F6C110 | 2011-11-08 22:51:55 | 4.25698 | 2.0189 | DEADBEEF
    22 | FAS235DQ92F6C110 | 2011-11-09 22:53:05 | 0       | 1.0568 | DEADBEEF
    23 | FAS235DQ92F6C110 | 2011-11-10 22:51:55 | 4.25698 | 2.0189 | DEADBEEF
    24 | FAS235DQ92F6C110 | 2011-11-11 22:53:05 | 0       | 1.0568 | DEADBEEF
    33 | A1B2C3D4E5F67890 | 2011-11-20 14:51:25 | 19.123  | 2.9765 | DEADBEEF
    34 | A1B2C3D4E5F67890 | 2011-11-21 14:51:54 | 1.90876 | 12.123 | DEADBEEF
    35 | A1B2C3D4E5F67890 | 2011-11-22 14:51:25 | 19.123  | 2.9765 | DEADBEEF
    36 | A1B2C3D4E5F67890 | 2011-11-23 14:51:54 | 1.90876 | 12.123 | DEADBEEF
```

I would like to do the following in a SQL statement, preferably using the Zend DB functions, but that is not required:

Based on 'serial' and 'addr', I want to add all of the power1's and power2's up for a month. So, in this table, I would want a query that returns a row of size 2 (one for each of 'power1' and 'power2'). If I look at the row for "November and 'serial'=DEADBEEF and 'addr'= FAS235DQ92F6C110", I want power1Sum to be ~8.5 and power2Sum to be ~6.2.

Does anyone know how to make this query in pure MySQL code or in the Zend framework?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Right now I have it in PHP. I pull in all the data and sort through it with if statements. I'm not good at SQL and don't know where to even start, which is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this may help you for Zend Framework.  This returns one row with the totals for the selected period.

Assume `$addr = 'FAS235DQ92F6C110'` and `$serial = 'DEADBEEF'`, this returns the totals for November 1 - 30, 2011.

```
$select = $table->select()
                ->from('power', array( 
                    'power1Sum' => 'SUM(power1)',
                    'power2Sum' => 'SUM(power2)'))
               ->where('serial = ?', $serial)
               ->where('addr = ?', $addr)
               ->where('timestamp >= ?', '2011-11-01')
               ->where('timestamp <= ?', '2011-11-30');

$result = $select->query();
if ($result) {
    $row = $result->fetch();
    echo 'Power 1 Sum = ' . $row['power1Sum'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Power 2 Sum = ' . $row['power2Sum'] . '<br />';
} else {
    echo "No results found.";
}
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks so much! I have one more question for you. Is there any way to get back an array of sums per day in the month? So, if I was interested in Nov, I would get back a row that had values for power1 and power2 for each day of the month.

Comment: Try adding `->group('DAY(timestamp)');` to the end of the query after the last where().

Comment: That works perfectly. I think I've got the hang of all of this now. Thank you so much, you have no idea how much you've helped me!